# using 'for' in template with two variables: django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to send two array to template in django, for example first=['a','b','c'] and second=['1','2','3'].

```
return render_to_response('temp.html',{'first':first, 'second':second}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

now in template i want to have a for which move through both arrays. some thing like:

```
{% for var1 in first and var2 in second %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
```

Can you please tell me what's the way?

Comment: That sounds like the type of logic that probably shouldn't go in the template. At most, it should go in a new template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use zip in your view like

```
mylist = zip(first , second)
```

pass it to template

```
return render_to_response('template.html', {'liste': mylist, ...
```

and just try this

```
{% for item1, item2 in liste %}
```

in your template .

hope this will help you

you can also try with https://github.com/gabrielgrant/django-multiforloop